# Error al ingresar datos a una bbdd mysql con python

Tags: python, mysql

Tengo un problema que no entiendo, si antes funcionaba correctamente y ahora se rompió toda la bbdd. Tengo las siguientes tablas

```sql
create table if not exists area(
    idArea int not null primary key auto_increment,
    nombreArea varchar(30) not null  
);
create table if not exists cargo(
    idCargo int not null primary key auto_increment,
    nombreCargo varchar(30) not null 
);
create table if not exists usuario(
    idUsuario int not null primary key auto_increment,
    usuario varchar(50),
    contrasenia varchar(50)
);
create table if not exists trabajador(
    idTrabajador int not null primary key auto_increment,
    rut varchar(13) not null,
    nombre varchar(50) not null,
    apellido varchar(50) not null,
    correo varchar(50) not null,
    telefono int not null,
    idArea_Trabajador int not null,
    idCargo_Trabajador int not null,
    idUsuario_Trabajador int not null,
    constraint fk_area_tr foreign key (idArea_Trabajador) references area (idArea) 
        on delete cascade on update cascade,
    constraint fk_cargo_tr foreign key (idCargo_Trabajador) references cargo (idCargo) 
        on delete cascade on update cascade,
    constraint fk_usuario_tr foreign key (idUsuario_Trabajador) references usuario (idUsuario) 
        on delete cascade on update cascade
)engine InnoDB;
```

Hace unas horas funcionaba de maravillas, pero ahora algo paso que la bbdd me manda errores de todo tipo, siempre acusando en la tabla de `trabajador` y un campo `idArea`, pero no se si es de la tabla `area` o de la tabla `trabajador`.

El código en python para ingresar es este, por ahora; por que lo he modificado infinidad de veces y no doy con la solución.

```
def inserta_trabajador(self,rut, nombre, apellido, correo, telefono, cargo, area, usuario):
    cur = self.cnn.cursor()
    sql='''INSERT INTO trabajador (rut, nombre, apellido, correo, telefono, idAreaTrabajador, 
    idCargoTrabajador, idUsuarioTrabajador) VALUES ('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', 
    '{}'), select * from trabajador'''.format(rut, nombre, apellido, correo, telefono, cargo, 
    area,usuario)
    cur.execute(sql)
    n=cur.rowcount
    self.cnn.commit()    
    cur.close()
    return n
```

Y esta es la función que la llama

```
def fGuardar(self):
    if self.id == -1:
        self.persona.inserta_trabajador(self.txtRut.get(), self.txtNombre.get(), self.txtApellido.get(), self.txtCorreo.get(), self.txtTelefono.get(), self.txtAreaArea.get(), self.txtCargoCargo.get(), self.txtIdUsuario)          
        messagebox.showinfo("Insertar", "Elemento insertado correctamente.")
    else:
        self.persona.modifica_trabajador(self.id, self.txtRut.get(), self.txtNombre.get(), self.txtApellido.get(), self.txtCorreo.get(), self.txtTelefono.get(), self.txtAreaArea.get(), self.txtCargoCargo.get(), self.txtIdUsuario.get())
        self.cargo.modifica_cargo(self.id, self.txtCargo.get())
        messagebox.showinfo("Modificar", "Elemento modificado correctamente.")
        self.id=-1
    self.limpiarGrid()
    self.llenarDatos()
    self.limpiarCajas()
    self.habilitarBtnGuardar("disabled")
    self.habilitarBtnOper("normal") 
    self.habilitarCajas("disabled")
```

No entiendo que le pasó a esta tabla si funcionaba de maravilla.

Comment: *...me manda errores de todo tipo...* pues, sin esos errores es más difícil poder ayudarte. ¿Podrías describir qué errores ocurren?

Comment: Creo que tienes un error tipográfico. En la variable `sql='''INSERT INTO trabajador ...`,  si observas al final hay un `, select * from trabajador` que no tiene ningún sentido tenerlo ahí, a lo mejor hiciste un *copiar-pegar* accidental. Borra ese pedazo de instrucción a ver qué pasa.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por el interes

Aqui el error princiapl

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
           values ('17854625-8','Karen', 'Valenzuela', 'karen@gmail.cl',...' at line 1
```

Lo curioso es que antes funcionaba de maravilla y de pronto colapso todo el crud a esa tabla